# Send byte array through socket between perl and Java

Tags: java, arrays, perl, client

I have a big issue with my java client.

Server: perl, with IO::Socket;

$n is the socket

```
    sub listen{    
 while(1){
  my $n = $_[0]->accept();
  my $thread;
  my $thread2;
  $thread = threads->create('talk', $n);
  $thread2 = threads->create('recu', $n);
 }
```

When a client send a message to the server

```
    sub talk{
 my $n = $_[0];
 while(<$n>){
  print $n $_;
 }
```

In 'talk' the server send the client message back to the client

Client: Java, in a Thread
  I send a byte array ->

```
static DataOutputStream os;
```

...

```
     public static void handleMsg(byte [] b){
  try {
   os.write(b);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }
```

->

```
<pre><code>
    byte[] buff = new byte[]{10,4};
ThreadListen.handleMsg(buff);
</code></pre>
I receive in the run() method only the first byte in the array (10)
<pre><code>
    public void run(){
  DataInputStream in = null;
  try{
   in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("in or out failed");
   System.exit(-1);
  }

  while(true){
   try{
    byte[] buff = new byte[6];
    int b = in.read(buff, 0, buff.length);
   }catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Read failed");
    System.exit(-1);
   }
  }
 }
```

If I try to send

```
byte[] buff = new byte[]{50,4};
ThreadListen.handleMsg(buff);
```

I receive nothing!!!

Did i missed something, I assume that if I send

```
byte[] buff = new byte[]{50,4};
```

I should receive 50,4 :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Perl code is doing `<$n>` so it's fetching data line-by-line. since 10 is the line-feed character, receiving a `{10,4}` sequence means it gets an empty line (which it prints back) and then a character 4. Even if it receives that (some debug messages in the Perl code would help), the print back to the socket may not complete if the socket is block-buffered (likely the default) without flushing the socket filehandle.

Comment: Understand - why when I send 10,4 I got 10 but when I send 50,4, I received nothing...

Comment: <$n> fetches line-by-line: it won't return anything until it encounters an end-of-line character (10) or the socket is closed by the other side. You need to use `read`, as mentioned by Hasturkun.

Comment: You mean something like this?:sub talkRead{
my $n = $_[0];
  my $data;
   while(1==1){
  $n->read($data, 1024);
  print $n $data;
   }
}

Comment: Are you sure it is only a Perl issue? I try with read but I got nothing, I will try again :)

Comment: the Java output stream might be buffered as well? DataOutputStream doesn't do buffering, though, so if you put that straight on top of the socket it shouldn't. I tend to use strace (on linux) to see the system calls to read/write etc. to debug exactly what's getting sent through in these situations.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `read` explicitly (instead of `readline` implicitly, which as the name suggests reads up to the end of the line, or EOF) to read from the socket.